# Disable comma separating category on Wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, wp-admin

We import data from external source. From this data we create custom post type and it's category. For example.

Post Name: Technology for blablabla
Category: Chemistry, Materials & Nanotechnology

Then when we edit this post on wp admin (add description) and click update post. The previously assigned category splits to two new categories (Chemistry and Materials & Nanotechnology).

How could I fix this so we wouldn't split categories by comma? [image]

Comment: You want `Materials & Nanotechnology` to split to two categories?

Comment: No, I do not want WP to split this category at all. Chemistry, Materials & Nanotechnology is the whole category name